# Codeigniter question mark in url

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have been using codeigniter, and facing a url problem, Actually i am trying to submit controller function parameters via url. Everything works fine but the only problem is question mark ? character. when i insert question mark in the url it automatically removes, Can anybody helps me

my url is

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/site/myfunction/parameter1/parameter2?/parameter3
```

Thanks

Comment: Are query strings enabled in the config? `$config[‘enable_query_strings’] = TRUE;`

Comment: yes query strings are enabled in the config file

Comment: actually i am trying to submit a question here

Comment: Have you tried adding it to `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';`?

Comment: yes i have added ? in this list

Comment: @h_a86 why are you using `?` if the parameter is already passed? There is no need for that, doing this `/myfunction/parameter1/parameter2?/parameter3` is enough

Answer (score 1):

`$config[‘enable_query_strings’] = TRUE;` in config file

Try this Url without segment i hope its work for you

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/site/myfunction/?p1=parameter1&p2=parameter2&p3=parameter3
```

Comment: Yes its enabled in my config file.

Comment: not working for me actually its not a query string i am using / as comment seperator. its part of question parameter

Comment: you just apply this function `print_r($_REQUEST)` in myfunction @h_a86 i hope result will be show

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to pass `?` as a regular character this will most probably help you

```
$link = urlencode("http://localhost/codeigniter/site/myfunction/parameter1/parameter2?/parameter3");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure "?" is in allowed url characters in codeignitor's config file.

Comment: yes its allowed by me. when i try to submit ? the browser removes the ?

Comment: @h_a86 I don't think it is the browser, it is about your `.htaccess`

Comment: Yes, definitely, its not the browser. It could be .htaccess or CodeIgnitor (stripping out malicious characters).
@h_a86 I think the "?" is part of the parameter2? If it is, urlencode the parameter i.e. change "?" to "%3f" and then decode it in the function.

Answer (score 0):

*Cannot pass parameter as a query string in codeigniter so try this below define code

**TestView.php:**

```
$id = '123';

<a  href="<?php echo base_url();?>'YourControllerName/YourFunctionName/<?php echo $id;?>'">
```

**Controller**

```
public function YourFunctionName($id)
    {
        if(empty($id))
        {
            echo "Success";
        }
        else{
            echo "Fail";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable query string in **config.php** file like

```
$config[‘enable_query_strings’] = TRUE;
```